# zoomed in login window

Tags: login, zooming

My niece was hitting the keyboard while the computer was at the login window, a few seconds later the login page was zoomed in like crazy as you can see.

[image: photo of the login window]

I tried hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and scrolling up and down. I also tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using these keyboard shortcuts to zoom in and out.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>+scroll with middle mouse button – Zoom in and out

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> – Turn zoom on or off
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> – Zoom in
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><sub>[image: IMG:]</sub></kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>  – Zoom out